# SQL DataReader Over Complex View

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hi all I'm a bit stumped on this one.

I have a relatively complex view on SQL2014 which combines the results of multiple tables into a single view.

I am then using a datareader in VB.NET to parse through the view which will then add it to various types.

The view works perfectly fine via management studio, but when I try and parse it via .NET it returns the number of fields but no rows, basically saying everything is DBNull. Yet the same .NET code works fine when looking directly over a table or another basic view.

Is there some kind of issue with SQL datareader and views which are constructed from analytic functions?

Note entify framework works fine for this view, but fails on a different view. I would rather use when data retrieval method for the entire solution.

Edit just tried using a stored procedure and it works fine too, very confused now.

Answer (score 0):

There are no inherent issues with .Net. data reader, and views like this. If you can see output in SQL Management Studio, then .Net can get access to it.

I have see this scenario occur in two common scenarios:

1. Bad requests from your application (i.e. you have added a filter that causes bad return data).
2. Modifying the data structure of one or more of the view's source tables without recompiling the view. This can result in all manner of strange results and behavior. Until it happens to you a few times, it can be very difficult to catch.